# Compact Riemann surface of genus 2 as the normalization of a quartic curve.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

I want to show that given a compact Riemann surface $X$ of genus 2, there is a map $\sigma:X\rightarrow \mathbb{CP}^2$, such that the followings are satisfied:

- $\sigma(X)$ is a quartic curve with a double point $s$
- $\sigma:X-\sigma^{-1}(s)\rightarrow \sigma(X)-s $ is biholomorphic.

---

What I have tried so far:

If we have found such map $\sigma$, then we can make a projection, $x = \pi \circ \sigma : X\rightarrow \mathbb{CP}^1$. And we can choose such projection that $\pi(s)$ is not a branch point of $x$.

Apply Riemann-Hurwitz formula, $\operatorname{deg}{R_x} = 6$. And we also have $\operatorname{deg}x = 4$.

I think there are more constraints on $x$, so that I can apply Riemann-Roch theorem to find such $x$ and then the quartic curve itself. But I don't know what to do next.

---

Any hints are welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider any divisor $D$ of degree 4 on $X$ (with $D \ne 2K_X$) and consider map $f \colon X \to \mathbb{P}^2$ given by the linear system $|D|$. It will have all the required properties.

Let me show that $f$ is almost injective. Assume $f(P) = f(Q)$ for a pair of points $P,Q \in X$. This means that $h^0(X,O_X(D-P-Q)) = h^0(D)-1 = 2$, hence $D - P - Q$ is a $g^1_2$, hence $D - P - Q = K_X$. This means that $P + Q \sim D - K_X$, and since $D - K_X \ne K_X$ (by the assumption $D \ne 2K_X$), the linear system $|D - K_X|$ consists of a unique divisor, hence $P$ and $Q$ are canonically defined up to permutation.

Comment: Would you please elaborate on it?

Comment: @Y.Hu: What do you want to see? The definition of a morphism given by a linear system? Something else? Please, specify.

Comment: I know the definition, but I can't see why it has all the required property. I know how to show that the image of the map lies in a quartic curve, for some certain $D$, but not the general case. Neither am I able to show that this map is injective with one exception.

Comment: @Y.Hu: OK, I added an explanation.

Comment: Is there an elementary way to explain this? I'm learning this following the book Introduction to Algebraic Curves by P.Griffiths. In that book, the      whole theory is given in terms of holomorphic/meromorphic functions and differentials on a compact Riemann surface. As you mentioned, $h^0(D-P-Q) = h^0(D) - 1 = 2$, may I interpret it as $\ell(D - P - Q) = \ell(D) - 1 = 2$? But I have no idea why $D - P - Q = K_X$. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Y.Hu if you follow Sasha's $h^0$ computations, then you have that $D - P - Q$ is a $g^1_2$ hence induces a degree $2$ map to $\mathbb P^1$. But every genus $2$ curve is hyperelliptic, and hyperelliptic curves are characterized by $K_X$ being the unique (up to linear equivalence) such divisor.

Comment: Now I see why this map is almost injective and that the image lies in a quartic curve. But I still don’t know why it maps surjectively onto that quartic curve. If the quartic curve is irreducible, an argument of connectedness will work. But is the quartic necessarily irreducible? If not, how to prove the surjectivity? Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

Given the answers above, I think I can show that this is a surjection by considering the regularization $\mu:\overline{Y}\rightarrow Y$ , where $Y$ is the quartic curve. We claim that $Y$ is irreducible. (Though the regularization is defined for irreducible curves in the book, the process can still be carried out for a general curve, and if it is reducible, $\overline{Y}$ would be disjoint union of regularizations of each factor.) Now $\mu^{-1}\circ\sigma$ extends to be a isomorphism between $X$ and a connected component of $\overline{Y}$. If $Y$ is reducible, $X$ would be the regularization of some curve with lower degree, which is impossible by checking the genus. Then we must have $X$ as the regularization of $Y$, which implies surjectivity.

(I still don't konw why $\sigma(X)$ lies in a quartic curve actually. I wish you could explain it to me.)

Comment: Well, let $D = P + Q + K_X$, where $P + Q$ is not linear equivalent to $K_X$. If I'm right, Riemann-Roch gives that $L(D-P-Q) = L(D-P) \subset L(D)$. Let $x,y$ be a basis of $L(D - P) = L(D - P -Q)$, and $z\in L(D) - L(D-P)$. Consider a set $S = \{x^iy^jz^k:i + j + k = 4, k < 4\}$,   which has 14 elements, all of them lying in $L(4D - P - Q)$, whose dimension is 13 by Riemann-Roch. Then we have a quartic equation.

Comment: I think your argument makes sense, I'm not sure though.

Comment: @y.hu I think your calculation is correct and, knowing the fact that $h^0(D-K_X)=1$, we can always assume that $D=P+Q+K_X$, so it applies to all such $D$  thx a lot !